# undefined method ..._index_path Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to get a basic form to work and am struggling because I keep getting the error

```
 undefined method `profiles_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x4fe1ba8>:0x4fccda0>
```

I have checked through and can't seem to work out where I am going wrong.

In my view (new.html.erb) I have:

```
 <%= form_for @profile do |f| %>

 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 <%= f.text_field :city %>
 <%= f.text_field :country %>
 <%= f.text_field :about %>

 <%= f.submit "Create Profile" %>

 <% end %>
```

In my profiles controller I have:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @title = "New Profile"
  @profile = Profiles.new
end

def create
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profiles.new(params[:profile])
  if @profile.save
    redirect_to profile_path, :notice => "Welcome to your new profile!"
  else
    render "profiles#new"
  end
end

def edit
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @title = "Update Profile"

  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])

  if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
    redirect_to profile_path
  else
    render action: "edit" 
  end
end

def index
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profiles.all
  @title = "Profile"
end

end
```

And finally in my profiles model I have

```
class Profiles < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

end
```

Any help people can offer really would be much appreciated because I am stumped. :)

Sorry forgot to include routes:

```
  controller :profiles do
   get "newprofile" => "profiles#new"
   get "updateprofile" => "profiles#update"
   get "profile" => "profiles#home"
  end

  resources :profiles, :controller => 'profiles'
```

Comment: do `rake routes` to check correct path to `index` method

Comment: What does your `routes.rb` file look like?

Comment: Hey, I have added my relevant routes file so that you can see what I have. The view is also called new.html.erb because it is for creating new profiles. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is indeed the way you've pluralized your model name. Don't do that. It should be a `Profile`, not a `Profiles`. There my be some work around to allow you to use a plural model name, but the answer is to stick to Rails convention rather than fighting the framework. Rename your model to `Profile` and the `url_for` helpers will understand how to correctly turn a new Profile object into a `/profiles` URL.

Comment: Amazing this seems to have worked! thanks for your help. Models = singular, controllers = plural are those always the rails rules?

Comment: Yes. Your models should always be singular and controllers should always be plural.

Answer (score 1):

If you run "rake routes" command, do "profiles_index" appear in your routes? Usually for the index page of a model, the work 'index' is left out so the route is `profiles_path`

You error probably comes from a view where you've used `profiles_index_path` instead of `profiles_path`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The view file is called new.html.erb because it's for creating new profiles - would be great to know what I need to change to fix this. Thanks again :)

Comment: You are not using 'profiles_index_path' in new.html.erb .. or you haven't posted all the code. I don't think the problem is in that view.

Comment: Strange isn't it! This is all the code and at no point do I reference profiles_index_path - yet the error is suggesting I do in the opening line form_for? The url I am trying to load is localhost:3000/newprofile

Comment: I can't realize what the problem is. Have you tried a global search through all your project for 'profiles_index_path' ?

Comment: Sadly it's definitely not used anywhere currently, the app isn't very extensive so it would be easy to find :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's failing due to the convention not being followed with your model name.

So I think you're problem is mostly around that you aren't following the convention on the model name, which would classically be singular, since each instance represents one profile. I think the form_for helper is trying to figure out what to do with it and failing as a result. So you have two options to try and resolve. Refactor the model name to singular (I'm not clear exacly how difficult that would be) or pass the :url paramater to form_for so it knows where to post to.

```
<% form_for @profile, :url => path_to_create_action do |f| %>
```

more information here:

Comment: Hi DVG, it is when I go to ../newprofile (which should be profile#new according to my routes). thanks!

Comment: What happens if you move `resources :profiles, :controller => 'profiles'` above the other routes?

Comment: still the same error sadly even if I move the resources to the top of the routes file. My model name is plural, @profile is singular though as is the call in form_for. cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help DVG, I had to turn my model singular - thanks for first highlighting this!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with **Rails 5** and I got the same error and it was specific using the word `Media` as my model and RoR used `Medium` as the plural so I got different routes when executing `rake routes`.

What I did to fix it was:

1. Delete the model I just have created.

   ```
   rails d scaffold Media
   ```
2. Edit `config/initializers/inflections.rb` with:

   ```
   ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
       # Here you can put the singular and plural form you expect
       inflect.irregular 'media', 'medias'
   end
   ```
3. Now execute the scaffold again:

   ```
   rails g scaffold Media
   ```

Now you must have everything in the way you expected. Because you have overwritten the ***Pluralizations*** and ***Singularizations*** ***(Inflections)*** in Ruby on Rails.

I hope it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace your form_for tag with the following?

```
<%= form_for @profile, :as => :post do |f| %>
```

It looks like it's trying to treat it as a GET request to "/profile". And, since it is not finding the index action, it craps out. I think forcing it to do a POST will fix this issue.

Comment: hey, sorry forgot to include that. The view file is called new.html.erb - any further help you can offer would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Hey Yosep, thanks for your help. Sadly I am still getting the same error however :( really don't know why it's getting confused!